# Tridion 2011 Core Service get keyword tcm from ComponentData

Tags: 2011, core-service, keyword

I'm getting the content from a component and in this content I have a field that represents a keyword. How could I get the tcm from that keyword? "etiquetas" field is my keywords.

```
<destacado_evento xmlns="uuid:65081b19-5ae5-4e3e-a9d0-371ce48b0694">
    <titulo>Evento Skyfall</titulo>
    <imagen xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:12-3580" xlink:title="Multimedia Ficha Evento" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
    <etiquetas>Nuestros compromisos</etiquetas>
    <fecha_inicio>2016-04-07T14:36:33</fecha_inicio>
    <fecha_fin>2016-04-16T20:00:48</fecha_fin>
</destacado_evento>
```

The problem is that I don't know the category. I get that information from:

```
foreach (ItemFieldDefinitionData field in schema.Fields)
{
    XmlElement schemaFields = contenidoComponentes.CreateElement(field.Name);
    schemaFields.InnerText = field.Description;
    schemaNode.AppendChild(schemaFields);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you load the Component with `LoadFlags.KeywordXlinks`, you will find that the XML elements representing Keyword field values get an `xlink:href` attribute which contains the Keyword ID (TCM URI or WebDAV URL depending on whether you also specify `LoadFlags.WebDavUrls` or not).

This is by far the cheapest way to get the Keyword IDs.

Comment: Hi Rick. Could you please show me an example of how it will be the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the title for the keyword and know the category attached to the component field, you can use below function to get the keyword id.

```
string GetKeywordId(string KeywordTitle, string categoryID)
{
    KeywordsFilterData kwdFilter = new KeywordsFilterData();

    var query1 = from XElement r1 in tridionClient.GetListXml(categoryID, kwdFilter).Descendants()
                 where r1.Attribute("Title").Value.ToLower() == KeywordTitle.ToLower()
                 select r1;
    XElement foundNode = query1.FirstOrDefault();
    if (foundNode != null)
    {
           string keywordID = foundNode.Attribute("ID").Value;
           return keywordID;
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Hello Saurabh. What is a tridionClient? because if I use my CoreServiceClient object, I don't have in it a method called GetListXml. Thanks